Редирект на другой сайт при нажатии кнопки "назад" в браузере
Нужно сделать Редирект на другой сайт при нажатии кнопки "назад" в браузере. Пробовал множество разных вариантов. Например такой:
window.history.pushState({}, ``, `https://www.google.com/`);

Ничего не работает. Можно ли вообще это реализовать?
Работает такой способ. НО только на мобильных браузерах. на десктопных работает в случае если открыть инструменты разработчика... как это может быть связано с "инструментами разработчика" ?
window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "");

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event){
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
    }
}


Аналогичный вопрос - https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.60399ac0-672c6ce3-f4c5d8bb-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application
